# When is a vector field conservative, and must the domain be simply connected for it to be conservative?

Tags: vector-fields

So I am working with some exams and stumbled upon this true/false problem:

**The vectorfield $G=[\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}]$ can be written as $G=\nabla \phi$ on an area $I$ that is simply connected in $R^2$ that does not contain $(0,0)$.**

So I am supposed to find out if this statement is true or false. The solution says true, and I don't understand why. If G is the gradient of a vectorfield $\phi$, must it not be conservative? And conservative vectorfields must be defined on a region that is simply connected. How can the problem say that it is defined on a simply connected domain when there is a hole in the domain? I know that in $R^3$ a simple connected domain can contain holes like this, but I not in $R^2$? So my question is then, must the domain be simply connected for a vectorfield to be conservative?

Comment: Conservative by definition means the line integral is path independent. Simply connectedness  of the domain of definition of the vector field has nothing to do with the definition of conservativeness. It is a **theorem** that on a simply connected domain, if a vector field has vanishing curl, then it is conservative. (The converse is not true; we can take a conservative field and restrict it to a non-simply connected set, but it is still conservative).

Comment: Ohh, I see. So G is conservative even though it has a hole $(0,0)$. But I have another question. The statements says that the area $I$ in $R^2$is simply connected and does not contain $(0,0)$. But I have read several times that a simply connected domain in $R^2$ can not contain any holes. So why does the statement then says that $I$ is simply connected?

Comment: No, I never said $G$ is conservative (and it is not). If you restrict $G$ to a simply connected open set $I\subset \Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$, then $G|_I$ is conservative. Also, I'm not sure what the confusion is about simply connectedness. $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ is not simply connected (and no one is claiming it is). But there are subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ which are simply connected (for example take a disc of radius $1$ centered at $(x,y)=(10,0)$... there are many other examples)

Comment: Ohh, I see now that I must have misunderstood the statement. I thought that $I$ was the whole $R^2$ except the origin. Now I understand what you mean. Thank you for your help :)